# Binding two models in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, checkbox, combobox, model, sapui5

I have two components, a multiComboBox and a checkbox.
And both of the components are binding with one model.
I want to know whether the data of the model can be connected in one way. If I select the checkbox, the comboBox is enabled. And if the comboBox is disabled, the property 'selected' of the checkbox cannot be changed.

```
var comboBox = new sap.m.MultiComboBox({
  enabled:'{isOthers}',
  });
var checkbox = new sap.m.CheckBox({
  selected: '{checked}'
});
```

Comment: When the combobox is disabled, how are you planning to select the checkbox then, to enable the combobox?

Comment: Also because you are already using javascript to create these controls, it would be the best to bind these properties via javascript, rather than passing a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this "*And if the comboBox is dis enabled, the property 'selected' of checkbox won't be changed.*", anyway, check the following code: [JS Bin Demonstration](https://jsbin.com/memebe/7/edit?html,js,output)